# jupyter notebook on AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I have set up a Jupyter notebook on an AWS box, or so I thought. When I try `jupyter notebook`, however, I get this:

[C 16:22:30.841 NotebookApp] The 'kernel_spec_manager_class' trait of  instance must be a type, but 'environment_kernels.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager' could not be imported

Any suggestions on how to fix?

**EDIT** actually, when I run jupyter notebook in the base environment, it works (I can't connect to it, but that's obviously a separate problem). However, in a "nonstandard" environment, it does not start. To answer the questions, this is an ubuntu 18.04 deep learning image, and in the environment I had installed jupyter and jupyterlab (via anaconda)

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be same as the one described here:

- [environment_kernels.EnvironmentKernelSpecManager could not be imported](https://github.com/ageron/tf2_course/issues/3)

Since in your question you have not indicated that you've tried that, I think that the solution proposed in the link could be tried:

```
pip install environment_kernels
```

Comment: Well, I just tried that, and I get:

pip install envirnoment_kernels
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement envirnoment_kernels (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for envirnoment_kernels

Comment: @IgorRivin Could you update your question with more details which linux you use (AL2, ubuntu) and what steps you took to install jupyter? I can try to replicate.

Comment: I gave more detail above, thanks! It is sort of a non-issue (because I can start jupyter notebook in the `base` environment, but it is puzzling, since I have never had this problem on any of my machines.

Comment: @IgorRivin I see. Sorry, I can't use ubuntu 18.04 deep learning image :-(